# Send Email once Database is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, ssms

I wondering if there is a way that for example is the LastUpdated Column in a table had not been updated for more than 10 minutes if I could use SQL mail to send an email to tell a user to check that all is still working correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You could create an agent task to do this, but I would *hope* that the every row in your table isn't being updated every 10 minutes. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), if I am honest. If there is an application problem, that should be the source of reporting the problem.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, theres a new entry into the table every 2-3 minutes. if there is not one after 10 minutes I want an email making me aware of this