# Is there a way to send SQL Mail when a table does NOT update?

Tags: sql-server, email, ssms

Looking to send a SQL Mail when a SQL Table does not update after a certain period of time.
Could this be done using a trigger to trigger an Agent job?

Comment: Why would a table *not* update? Sending emails from a trigger is generally a bad idea, and a `TRIGGER` would trigger on the rows being updated; if they aren't updated then the trigger doesn't happen. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I'd setup a SQL job, with a stored procedure to check the table periodically and send out an email as needed...

Comment: What does `does not update after a certain period` mean? If you decide what that means and how to express it in a SQL query you can write a job that runs periodically and checks if that query produces results

Comment: An application updates the database table so if the table is not updated I know there is an issue with the application as soon as it happens.

Comment: If the table doesn't `UPDATE` then you would have received an error; so you can then let the user know at that point and handle the sending of the email in your application.

Comment: @ShawnMurray this means you need monitoring for that application, not a SQL Mail job.

Comment: After a certain period of time. So after 10 minutes if there is no database entries. send an email

Comment: *"An application updates the database table so if the table is not updated I know there is an issue"* and *"So after 10 minutes if there is no database entries. send an email "* Are completely *different* scenarios... YOu need to decide what the problem you're trying to solve is first, and then [edit] your question to actually tell us what that problem is.

Comment: @Brandon how would i do this?

Comment: What kind of application is it? A SQL Server Agent job? A Scheculed task? Something else? Why not add monitoring to that application, or configure SQL Server Agent or Windows' Scheduled Tasks to send alerts if the job fails? Why check *in*directly/

Comment: @Larnu They are the same as the application writes to the database. so if there is no entries there is an issue and the application does not always throw an error that is why i need sql to check

Comment: Processing an `UPDATE` statement and it failing, and a table not receiving an `UPDATE` statements in the last 10 minutes are *nothing* alike, @ShawnMurray . If your `UPDATE` statement is failing, and the application isn't flagging that error, then you need to review that and find out why.

Comment: This question does, however, seem to be a duplicate of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598462/send-email-once-database-is-updated).

Comment: @ShawnMurray: See below...

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example SQL...you'll need a DBA to [setup db mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15) and [setup a SQL job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-transact-sql-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15) to call the stored procedure...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTableHere
(
    TableId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Field1 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    LastUpdated DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableHere (Field1) VALUES ('Value1');
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableHere (Field1) VALUES ('Value2');
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableHere (Field1) VALUES ('Value3');
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SendEmailIfYourTableHasntBeenUpdated
AS
    DECLARE @CheckForUpdatesAfter DATETIME2 = DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, GETDATE());
    DECLARE @NumberOfUpdates INT = 0;

    SELECT @NumberOfUpdates = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTableHere WHERE LastUpdated > @CheckForUpdatesAfter;
    
    IF @NumberOfUpdates = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
            @profile_name = 'dbmail',  
            @recipients = 'your.team@yourcompany.com',  
            @subject = 'dbo.YourTableHere hasn''t been updated in 10 minutes',  
            @body = '<b>Don''t just stand there, do something!',
            @body_format = 'HTML'; 
    END;
GO
```